# Could this "question" be converted to an answer, to a protected question?

Tags: support, protected-questions, new-users

A new user posted a [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131070/whatsapp-is-not-working-with-mobile-data-in-vodafone) that is really an answer.
As @AndrewT observed, it seems to be an answer to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48085/whatsapp-doesnt-work-over-3g-everything-else-works-fine) protected question.

While I cannot determine if the answer is correct, it does seem to provide value.
I would like to see this post become an answer to the question.
Could we

- Convert it to an answer?
- Or, as an alternative, temporarily remove protection from the question, so that the answerer can post this as an answer?

Obviously, we can wait for the new user to gain 10 rep on this site, but it seems that this poster simply has an answer to 1 question. I see little good in encouraging a new user to start rep-farming, just to be able to post a single answer.

So - can we lend this new user a little hand, so that their post ends up where it belongs?

Comment: Why not make a community wiki post on poster's behalf?

Comment: @Firelord Copy-pasting the poster's answer as a CW answer? Because even if it's CW the OP needs rep to edit it. It's an option, but I'd rather see that post as a normal answer.

Comment: I don't  think rep is needed to make changes. Rep is needed for edit applies immediately privilege  (for CW wiki post, 100 points are required). Test: http://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/119634

Comment: @Firelord OK, so anonymous users can suggest edits to CW posts. The advantage of CW would be that it would say how many % of the answer came from Deepika. There's something to be said for this, but I'm still hoping for a solution where it becomes a normal answer.

Comment: Moderators can't convert posts into answers. We can remove the protection, but we have no idea if the user will even return to the site unless they come here and state a desire to repost it. Since it is old (2+ years) I'll unprotect it, but it if winds up needing to be protected again in the meantime then the user will simply need to earn some rep.

Comment: @eldarerathis Thanks! Seems a good solution to me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is deepika's answer, reformatted and ready to be converted into either a community wiki answer or a normal answer to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48085/whatsapp-doesnt-work-over-3g-everything-else-works-fine) protected question.

---

I tried this and now it's working perfectly.

1. Turn on your Mobile Data.
2. Select *Settings* -> *SIM Management* -> Turn on Data Roaming (or) on the notification slide (while sliding from the top) select *APN Switch* and then turn on Data roaming.
3. Select *Back*. Select *Access point names*.
4. Now you can able to view 4 options. Select *Vodafone Connect* and then press *Add* button (in the top right corner).
5. Now you have to edit your settings.
6. Click on *Server* (7th point). At default it shows *Not set*. Enter www.google.co.in. Select *OK*.
7. Select Authentication type as *Not set* (13th Point).
8. Select APN type as *Not set* (14th Point).
9. Select APN Protocol as *IPv4* (15th Point).
10. Select APN Roaming Protocol as *IPv4* (16th Point).
11. Select Bearer as *unspecified* (18th Point).
12. Select *Menu/Settings*. Select *Save*.
13. Come back and select your preferred network type as *WCDMA Only for 3G*.
14. Come back and select network operators and allow it select automatically or manually.
15. Then it shows *Vodafone In 3G*. Select it. Then it shows *Registered on network*.

Now restart/reboot your phone, and you're ready to operate your phone with your mobile data.

Comment: This should help to keep Deepika's answer visible if their post gets deleted. Thank you for that. However, it doesn't answer the actual question. I'd really like a solution where Deepika gets to post the answer themselves.

Comment: I agree with you,  but I don't know how to give a better answer to your question than merely providing a stopgap solution.

Comment: It'll probably require moderator intervention. I guess even moderators cannot convert a question into an answer. But they, and some high-rep users, should be able to un-protect a question - and then protect it again.